# How to deduct balance from sqlite column after user input and update?

Tags: android, sqlite

I set balance as 15.00 in SQLite and I want to retrieve the balance, and then subtract the value with input by user in edittext (example 3.50) and then update back the new balance (11.50) in SQLite. So may I know what should I do now?

DatabaseHelper.java

```
package com.example.calculator;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    static final String DB_NAME = "test.db";
    static final int DB_VERSION = 1;
    public static final String table = "wallet";
    public static final String id = "_id";
    public static final String bal = "balancewallet";

    private static final String CREATE_TABLE = "create table " + table + "(" + id
            + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + bal + " REAL NOT NULL);";

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context){
        super(context,DB_NAME,null,DB_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + table);
        onCreate(db);
    }
}
```

DBManager.java

```
package com.example.calculator;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;

public class DBManager {
    private DatabaseHelper databaseHelper;
    private Context context;
    private SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase;

    public DBManager(Context c){
        context = c;
    }

    public DBManager open() throws SQLException {
        databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
        sqLiteDatabase = databaseHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;
    }

    public void close(){
        databaseHelper.close();
    }

    public void insert (String balan){
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(DatabaseHelper.bal, 15.00);
        sqLiteDatabase.insert(DatabaseHelper.table,null,contentValues);
    }

    public Cursor fetch(){
        String[] columns = new String[] { DatabaseHelper.id, DatabaseHelper.bal};
        Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.query(DatabaseHelper.table, columns, null, null,null, null,null);
        if (cursor != null){
            cursor.moveToFirst();
        }
        return cursor;
    }

    public int update (long _id, String balan){
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(DatabaseHelper.bal, balan);
        int i = sqLiteDatabase.update(DatabaseHelper.table, contentValues, DatabaseHelper.id + "=" +_id, null);
        return i;
    }

}
```

I want to display the balance first into textview, then only deduct the value. After that, display the new balance and update it in SQLite.
MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.calculator;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.text.DecimalFormat;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private DBManager dbManager;

    EditText number1, number2;
    TextView result, money;
    Button subtract;

    float result_num, num1, num2;

    DecimalFormat formater = new DecimalFormat("0.00");

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        dbManager = new DBManager(this);
        dbManager.open();

        // I want to display first the balance before subtract
        // but not sure if this is correct or not
        Cursor cursor = dbManager.fetch();
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        final TextView money = this.findViewById(R.id.money);
        money.setText(cursor.getString(1));

        result = findViewById(R.id.result);
        number1 = findViewById(R.id.number1);
        number2 = findViewById(R.id.number2);
        subtract = findViewById(R.id.subtract);


        subtract.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // I want to pass balance from money(from database) into num1
                // but I know the code below is not fetching the value from money
                num1 = Float.parseFloat(number1.getText().toString());
                num2 = Float.parseFloat(number2.getText().toString());
                result_num = num1 - num2;
                result.setText(formater.format(result_num));
                //then i dont know how to take this result and update into sqlite and display in textview(money)
            }
        });


    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, then changing the `result.setText(formater.format(result_num));` line to the following should work:

```java
String result_string = formater.format(result_num);
result.setText(result_string);
dbManager.update(1, result_string);
money.setText(result_string);
```

(that `1` might need to be a `0` depending upon what id the DB row was assigned).

As an additional improvement, I would advise you to avoid passing numbers as strings into `contentValues` since SQLite will just have to turn it back into a number anyway. And that way you cannot accidentally pass say `""` to that method. So I think you should change `public int update (long _id, String balan){` to `public int update (long _id, Float balan){` and then change the `dbManager.update(1, result_string);` line above to `dbManager.update(1, result_num);`

Comment: Thank you for your answer but may I know how do I pass the value of balance from database into num1 (in MainActivity.java)

Comment: You could change `money.setText(cursor.getString(1));` to `final String money_string = cursor.getString(1); money.setText(money_string);` and then use `number1.setText(money_string);` after `number1` is set.

Comment: Ohh I see. Okay but one more question(hopefully), is it possible if I want to pass the value of number1.setText(money_string) to num1?

Comment: `num1` is a `float`, so you'd need to do `Float.parseFloat` or something similar to set `num1` to the value of `money_string`. (I assume that's what you meant, since the value `number1.setText(money_string)` returns is `void`, AKA no value.)